# List of files and folders under a parent folder from Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, api, google-drive-api, jstree

I'm working with a file based tree based on JsTree. Currently, I'm getting a file lists object by using the `q` parameter like the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='0B_J9f9IAYIKQdllaQXJQXzMyZm8'+in+parents"
```

The above URL returns a list of file objects under a parent folder. However, if there're more folder under the parent folder then I'd also like to fetch those files too recursively. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do files.list with no search parm (q) it will return a list of all the files and directories.

If you tell it you want the ones with the parent is x then its going to return to you everything where parent is x.  so the sub folder items will have the parent of y and not x so you aren't going to return them.

**Option 1:**

do files.list get everything and sort it yourself.

**Option 2:**

do files.list with your search parm (q) when the results are returned check if there are any folders and do files.list with search parm (q) again for this next folder.

By adding q you are telling it you want only the ones with this parent you aren't going to get the results for the sub folders.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Option one would require a long list of sorting when there would a huge file list and it will also take the time to query everything.

However, I was also thinking about the option 2. But, do you've any solution how can I set the data to the JsTree when the data will return from the second query (I'll make another request when there'd be any child folder).

Comment: your going to have to buffer it or something there is no other way of doing it. you can only request data for one request at a time.

Comment: I can recursively search for files when a folder would be found. However, I'm not sure how we can continuously search for files when there would a new folder.